# Can `match` be faster than `rewrite`

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

When writing `Ltac` in Coq, one might be tempted to write

```
try match goal with
 |- context [?x && true] => rewrite andb_true_r
end
```

instead of

```
try rewrite andb_true_r
```

to not call `rewrite` pointlessly – this inside the inner loop of a larger tactic, and we expect the rewrite to *fail* in most cases.

But is that actually faster? Or does `rewrite` fail just as fast as the hand-written `match` that I wrote?

Comment: What does benchmarking say?

Comment: You mean compared to `rewrite ?andb_true_r.` ?

Comment: I am trying it right now, but somehow the whole proof breaks…

Comment: You might want to try `rewrite 1?andb_true_r.`, because `rewrite ?andb_true_r.` rewrites as many times as possible and may not rewrite at all, i.e. it does not fail.

Comment: I know, but I doubt that affects the time it takes for `rewrite` to fail much. I’ll clarify the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on your self-answer, Coq is sensitive to the exact matching strategy used.  Note the difference between the following tactics:

```
Require Import Coq.Bool.Bool.

Goal forall b, b = true.
  intros.
  (* Create a large goal *)
  do 300 rewrite <- orb_false_r with (b := b).
  Time do 300 try idtac.
  (* Finished transaction in 0.001 secs (0.004u,0.s) (successful) *)
  Time do 300 try match goal with |- context [_ || true] => idtac end.
  (* Finished transaction in 0.108 secs (0.108u,0.s) (successful) *)
  Time do 300 try match goal with |- context [_ || ?b] => constr_eq b true end.
  (* Finished transaction in 3.21 secs (3.208u,0.s) (successful) *)
  Time do 300 try rewrite orb_true_r.
  (* Finished transaction in 2.862 secs (2.863u,0.s) (successful) *)
```

I suspect that `rewrite` is using a matching strategy similar to the `match` I wrote with `constr_eq`; it finds looks at occurrences of `orb ?a ?b`, and then tries to instantiate evars from left to right and do syntactic equality checking as need be.  This incurs a large cost, apparently.  I've opened [an issue on Coq's bug tracker](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/6860).

However, this cost might be unavoidable, as `rewrite` does matching modulo β, unlike your `match`.  Consider:

```
Goal forall b, b || (fun x => x) true = true.
  intros.
  Fail match goal with |- context [_ || true] => rewrite orb_true_r end.
  rewrite orb_true_r. (* succeeds *)
```

The speedup is even more apparent in `setoid_rewrite`, which does rewriting modulo unfolding in many cases, and thus can needlessly perform reduction in your goal, failing over and over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is! I achieved a 60% speed-up in one of my tactics.

Here is another micro-benchmark showing this behaviour:

```
Require Import Coq.Bool.Bool.

Goal forall b, b = true.
intros.
(* Lets create a large goal *)
do 300 rewrite <- orb_false_r with (b := b).
Time do 300 try rewrite orb_true_r.
(* Finished transaction in 2.57 secs (2.431u,0.003s) (successful) *)
Time do 300 try lazymatch goal with |- context [_ || true] => rewrite orb_true_r end.
(* Finished transaction in 0.05 secs (0.05u,0.s) (successful) *)
Abort.
```

Comment: `rewrite`, as well as `match` have many different tradeoffs, so depending on the situation they can be slower or faster. Are you using vanilla `rewrite` ? It is known to be slow, you may want to see how the matching in ssreflect's version `rewrite` impacts your benchmarks.

Comment: In your example ssr's rewrite is about twice slower.

Comment: Note that the tactic is called `setoid_rewrite`, not `rewrite_setoid`.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `rewrite` doesn't call `setoid_rewrite` (which often succeeds where `rewrite` alone fails). `setoid_rewrite` is also vastly more expensive than `rewrite` in many cases and often worth avoiding for that reason.

Comment: The docs say “Moreover, all the corresponding unprefixed tactics (i.e. reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity, replace, rewrite) have been extended to fall back to their prefixed counterparts when the relation involved is not Leibniz equality.” so in some cases, they do fall back to `setoid_rewrite`, but you are right: not in this case, because the equality is `eq`